# How can we stop a client connection from mosquito broker?

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, broker

I have multiple devices sending messages to a mosquito broker. I would like to manage a kind of device revocation so that when a device is revoked, I want the mosquito broker to automatically close the connection for this specific device.

Is there any command or way to ask the broker to explicitly close a connection to a specific client?

Thanks in advance,
hak

Comment: Add the client source port to the firewall reject rules. Should work, have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can kick an already connected client.

But what you can do if using the Authentication Plugin (either a 3rd party or the included dynamic security plugin) to change the ACL that the user can publish/subscribe to which should effectively stop the client sending or receiving any messages and when it next tries to connect it will not be allowed.

Comment: I'm not going to suggest this as an answer, but another possibility - if you know the IP address and port number the client is connecting from is to block that at the broker's firewall for longer than the MQTT keep-alive time.